# Using count if and sum with the range defined on two cells in excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

IMAGE OF THE FORMAT BEING USED:

[image]

Hello,
i have been trying to use the count if and the sum fucntion. The cell range of teh function should be taken from two other cells. is there any way to do that? i have been racking my brain for two days now. i have attached a picture for reference or an idea as to how it might happen.

thank you for your help

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: how do i define the range of the countif and sum function based on the value of another cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a range using INDIRECT().

Indirect works as follows. 
You build a range using text e.g. 
INDIRECT("A"&A1). If A1 contains the number 8, indirect will reference cell A8.

If you want to reference a range you do it like this. INDIRECT("A"&A1":B"&A2). If A1 contains 8 and A2 contains 10 this indirect will make the reference of "A8:B10".

Comment: Thank you, saved my life and it worked. slightly modified it to look more like this COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&K3):INDIRECT("D"&L3);J8)

Comment: You can modify it further to  `COUNTIF(INDIRECT("D"&K3&":D"&L3);J8)`. This eliminates the second indirect.